# Getting duplicates when i try to iterate results from mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following SQLALCHEMY CODE

```
    my_query = db.session.query(Isps.isp_name, Ratings.rating_value,
    services.service_name, Service_metric.metric_name)
```

the above basically translates to this ,when i dump my query

```
SELECT isps.isp_name AS isps_isp_name, ratings.rating_value 
AS   ratings_rating_value, services.service_name 
AS services_service_name,      service_metric.metric_name 
AS service_metric_metric_name 
FROM isps, ratings, services, service_metric
```

if i do a for loop on the my_query like this

```
for data in my_query:
    print data.isp_name
```

this will give me duplicates

```
ISP1
ISP2
ISP3
ISP1
ISP1
ISP2
ISP3
ISP1
```

AND so on and so on.

my guess its looping through the other tables as well there by giving me duplicates

NB:THESE TABLES ARE UNRELATED , I AM SELECTING ALL THE DATA SO I CAN USE IT A DROPDOWNS ON MY FORM

Comment: That's what happens when you do cross joins ("Cartesian products").  What are you expecting if you don't use proper `join` syntax?

Comment: Can you show us the columns of each of the tables in your join?

Comment: Please note that the tables are unrelated ,what i want to achieve is selecting those specific fields and be able to reference them in a form , like for example dropdowns in a form that are  populated using the data from the database  isps has 3 columns id , isp_name ,isp_descpription  services table has id ,service_name

Answer (score 2):

What you're likely looking for is something like this.

Warning, I don't know what your schema looks like, so the names here (and possibly the actual structure) are probably off.

```
SELECT i.isp_name, 
    COALESCE(AVG(r.rating_value), 'n/a') AS avg_rating, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.rating_id) AS num_ratings,
    s.service_name,
    sm.metric_name 
FROM isps AS i
    LEFT JOIN ratings AS r ON r.isp_id = i.isp_id
    INNER JOIN services AS s ON i.service_id = s.service_id
    INNER JOIN service_metric AS sm ON s.metric_id = sm.metric_id
GROUP BY i.isp_name
```

What you're doing is joining on the domain tables (services and service metric) by their Foreign Key in the isps table, and on the ratings table by the isp id.

This will give you relativity in your query results - you'll get the services that relate to the isps, and not the "Cartesian Product' Gordon mentioned above, where you retrieve every service joined with every isp, for example.

To accomplish a `JOIN` in SQLAlchemy, use a `select_from` clause with a `join` clause as an arg, e.g.: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.join

The GROUP clause at the end will cluster your data such that only one ISP is returned per row.

However, then you have to aggregate tables that might return multiple results against a single ISP (e.g. ratings).

We do that by using aggregate functions, like AVG and COUNT to extract meaningful data from a group of values.

To do this in SQLAlchemy, use a `count` with a `group_by` clause: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count

Comment: i was hoping to use the SQLALCHEMY syntax since i am using it as my underlying SQL library ...

Comment: @Chamambom you'll want to use JOIN syntax, with a `select_from` clause, as defined here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.join

Answer (score 0):

Well here is another idea. How about you create a view in your Database, that will put all the values you want into 2 Columns?

```
CREATE
 ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
 DEFINER = root@localhost
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 VIEW `v`
 AS 
select `isps`.`isp_name` AS `VALUE`,'ISP_NAME' AS `TYPE` from `isps` 
union all 
select `ratings`.`rating_value` AS `VALUE`,'RATING_VALUE' AS `TYPE` from `ratings` union all 
select `services`.`service_name` AS `VALUE`,'SERVICE_NAME' AS `TYPE` from `services` 
union all 
select `service_metric`.`metric_name` AS `VALUE`,'METRIC_NAME' AS `TYPE` from `service_metric`
```

Now you should be able to query that view in python. When you loop through them you should get no duplicate entrys. 
If you want to populate dropdowns in a form you can simply add a filter to your query and select them by the "TYPE" from the view.